# Do changes in GCC mangling affect ABI compatability?

Tags: c++, gcc, abi

[Documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html) for

> -fabi-version

says this[only part here]:

> [...]
> Version 11, which first appeared in G++ 7, corrects the mangling of
> sizeof... expressions and operator names. For multiple entities with
> the same name within a function, that are declared in different
> scopes, the mangling now changes starting with the twelfth occurrence.
> It also implies -fnew-inheriting-ctors.
>
> Version 12, which first appeared in G++ 8, corrects the calling
> conventions for empty classes on the x86_64 target and for classes
> with only deleted copy/move constructors. It accidentally changes the
> calling convention for classes with a deleted copy constructor and a
> trivial move constructor.
>
> Version 13, which first appeared in G++ 8.2, fixes the accidental
> change in version 12.
>
> Version 14, which first appeared in G++ 10, corrects the mangling of
> the nullptr expression.
>
> Version 15, which first appeared in G++ 11, changes the mangling of
> __ alignof __ to be distinct from that of alignof, and dependent operator names.

My question is do this mangling changes(so not for example calling conventions change, but changes in Version14 and Version15) affect ABI compatability, of will during link time linker just pick one and everything will be great?

note: presume I am using those things, although I doubt that most people use those in API boundaries.

Comment: Why would they affect the ABI version if they didn't affect ABI compatibility?

Comment: @eerorika maybe gcc people do consider linker dropping different but same stuff problematic? I am just guessing, I have no idea, that is why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, each ABI version is incompatible, but most of the changes affect only rare cases, and hopefully certain versions like 12 are rare because they were fixed quickly.  The reason such changes are made at all is usually that certain things mangle to the **same** name, which breaks even if only one component uses it rather than needing two to be incompatible.